# Passing arguments in Meteor.subscribe

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

When can I pass an argument when I am subscribing to a published collection?

I am publishing my collection like this:

```
Meteor.publish('recent-posts', function (options) {
  var limit = options.limit;
  return Posts.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: limit});
});
```

In my routes file, I can pass `{limit: 5}` as `options` like this, and it works:

```
...
waitOn: function () {
  return Meteor.subscribe('recent-flights', {limit: 5});
}
...
```

What confuses me is that this also works:

```
...
waitOn: function () {
  return Meteor.subscribe('recent-posts', {date: this.params.date});
}
...
```

The second example subscribes me to all the posts with a certain date value.

Why does it work? It seems like I am passing `{date: this.params.date}` as `options`. But I have not defined anything about `date` in my `Meteor.publish`.

Comment: did you try to use directly `limit` too? It should work as well. I think you don't need to define anything as `date` in your publish function: you pass it in the `option` array parameter, containing a key labeled `date`. You can use it from there, it is already named inside the `option` array.

Comment: Show us your entire route code.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in `Meteor` would lead to such a behavior, at least as far as I can tell from the source code. I also tested your example in a "clean" meteor instance. An it did not behave as you describe. So it must be something in your code doing this. It could also be, that you aren't describing your problem correctly.

I also noticed that in you are using two different subscriptions in your example; `recent-posts` and `recent-flights`. So that might be the source of your confusion.